# Problem with Sign & Distribute Xamarin.Forms iOS app

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms

[image]

I'm trying to upload a Xamarin.Forms iOS app to the App Store through the Application Loader from the Archives screen in Visual Studio for Mac.

Somehow the "Next" button is not enabled in the "Sign & Distribute" screen. I'm not getting any error message or other type of feedback from Visual Studio.

What could be the cause of this, and how could I fix it?

Comment: Are you using the latest Visual Studio for Mac? The profile has the same package id as the app?

Comment: It's the latest stable build of Visual Studio for Mac. And the package IDs are the same.

Comment: @RenéWiersma It seems you only create a provisioning profile for your containing app. The watch and watch extension apps also need a valid provisioning profile for submission.

Comment: @LandLu-MSFT That was I was thinking as well. When I go to the Project options, to the Bundle Signing tab, both the WatchApp and the WatchAppExtension have valid Distribution Provisioning Profiles. Am I missing something?

Comment: @RenéWiersma Have you chosen the corresponding provisioning profile in the configuration window for watch app while archiving?